# Trying to obtain sum of random prime numbers read from a file?

Tags: c++, file, variables, nested-loops, primes

I am trying to read a random amount of numbers from a list in a file.  From those numbers, I need to decide whether or not the numbers themselves are prime, then I need to add all of the prime numbers together to get their sum.

I am having issues with this block of my code.  I'm sort of lost on how to go about obtaining the values that ARE prime and storing them so I can add them together to get their cumulative sum.  I think this part of the code would go in my `else if` block, but I'm not 100% sure.  Would someone be able to point me in the right direction and/or give me an example?  If I wanted to obtain their average, can I do so in a similar way to obtaining their sum?

Also, there are multiple values being pulled from my list, so if I use a single variable to represent a prime number, will the variable reset itself to the next prime number it finds every time the entire loop iterates?

```
bool primeCalc()
{
    int number;
    bool primeValue = true;
    int i;
    while (inputFile >> number)
    {
        for (i = 2; i <= number / 2; ++i)
        {
            if (number % i == 0)
            {
                primeValue = false;
                break;
            }
            else if (number % i > 0)
            {
                // some code to store number value for sum; 

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: I would highly encourage you to write a function that takes a number and returns either **true** or **false** depending on whether or not that number is a prime

Comment: You don't need to store them. Just test if the current number is prime. If it is, add it to the total.

Comment: You can improve the prime testing.  You only need to test while `i * i <= number`; you can test for 'divisible by 2' outside the loop, and then test odd numbers in the loop.  This radically reduces the amount of testing and dramatically speeds up the code.  These are baby steps in improving the testing, but they're enough to make a huge difference.  For example, testing 37, your code goes through 18 iterations, but the suggested code goes through 3 iterations.  And the benefit increases as the size of the numbers increase. Your code would execute 498 iterations to test 997; the alternative 15.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why store them and waste space? Do it as they come from the stream, like this:

```
int sum = 0;
while(inputFile >> number)
{
  if(isPrime(number))
    sum += (number);
}
```

where `isPrime` could be a function of this prototype: `bool isPrime(int number);`, which returns `true` if `number` is prime, otherwise false.

Comment: Your actual function returns `int`; your sample prototype returns `bool`.  Too much C coding?  And why not `return false;` when you spot a composite and only `return true;` at the end when none of the candidate factors are a factor?  It simplifies the loop testing.  The `else` also becomes unnecessary if you return as soon as you can.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't have to check till number/2, checking till the square root of the number is enough. That is, replace

```
for (i = 2; i <= number / 2; ++i) {
    // stuff
}
```

with

```
for (i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++) {
    // stuff
}
```

and you don't need the else statement. Just define an integer variable to accumulate the prime numbers right in an if-statement like:

```
if(primeValue) acc+=number;
```

After the for-loop an inside the while-loop. You also need to set primeValue as true just before the for-loop and again inside the while-loop.

If you want the average of those numbers, you can use a counter and increment it where you accumulate the sum and after the while-loop, you can divide the sum by the counter.

Comment: Note that computing `sqrt(number)` on each iteration is not a good idea, though a modern optimizing compiler might avoid it for you.  Using `sqrt()` involves conversion to `double`, calculation, and conversion back to `int`, too.